# FTP source - obtaining file reference each time a file is transferred

Tags: spring-xd

lets say i create a stream like this:

```
stream create --name ftpstream --definition "ftp --username=ftpuser --password=pass123 --host=host.com --remoteDir=/home/ftpuser --mode=ref | log" --deploy
```

If FTP server contains two files both will be transferred and log sink will log something like this:

```
2017-10-24T20:43:08+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-3 sink.ftpstream - /tmp/xd/ftp/dummy.txt
2017-10-24T20:43:08+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-3 sink.ftpstream - /tmp/xd/ftp/test.txt
```

However, this print only happens the first time a new file is processed(if i add a new file to FTP server, sink log will log message)
but if i delete already transferred files from local `/tmp/xd/ftp` directory, files will be transferred again but no sink log message is written.

How to correctly get the file reference each time a file is transferred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom FTP source - the default source has an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` in its `local-filter` so it won't pass the same file twice (even though it's fetched).

If you use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`, it will pass the file if the `lastModified` date changes.

Comment: Thanks, i have read the docs and what you proposed should do the trick. It also says that from the spring-integration version 4.3.8 FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter should be a default setting.